# How to use go router with TabBarView in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I want to create 3 pages using NavigationBar, body using TabBarView with AutomationKeepAliveClientMixin (to keep page state). The subpages of these 3 pages do not have NavigationBar.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TubO.png)

My goRouter part looks like this:

```
GoRoute(
  name: "home",
  path: "/",
  builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
),
GoRoute(
  name: "settings",
  path: "/settings",
  builder: (context, state) => const SettingsPage(),
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      name: "settings-edit",
      path: "edit",
      builder: (context, state) => const SettingsEditPage(),
    ),
  ]
),
GoRoute(
  name: "calendar",
  path: "/calendar",
  builder: (context, state) => const CalendarPage(),
)
```

I followed the instructions from [https://docs.page/csells/go_router/nested-navigation](https://stackoverflow.com). But I can't understand why it doesn't work properly, maybe because I created many different GoRouters, but in the tutorial there is only 1.

I also followed the 2 instructions at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71011598/how-to-work-with-navigationbar-in-go-router-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com).

1.with ShellRouter and using GlobalKey<NavigatorState>() it works but cannot be used with TabBarView and also does not retain page state.

2.With StatefulShellRoute it seems more modern, but I also don't know how to use it in TabBarView

Finally I was able to temporarily get it working by leaving the TabBarView in the ShellRoute, and using _rootNavigatorKey to bring the child pages out.

```
// go router
GoRoute(
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  ShellRoute(
    builder: (context, state, child) => MainPage(location: state.uri.toString()),
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        name: "home",
        path: "/",
        builder: (context, state) => const SizedBox(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: "settings",
        path: "/settings",
        builder: (context, state) => throw "",
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            name: "settings-edit",
            path: "edit",
            parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
            builder: (context, state) => const SettingsEditPage(),
          ),
        ]
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: "calendar",
        path: "/calendar",
        builder: (context, state) => throw "",
      ),
    ]
  )
)

// main Page
class MainPage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final String location;
  const MainPage({required this.location, super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends ConsumerState<MainPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final TabController _tabController;
  int currentPageIndex = 0;

  late List<Map<String, dynamic>> menu = [
    {
      "location": "/",
      "page": const HomePage(),
    },
    ....
  ];

  void changePage({String? location}) {
    int index = menu.indexWhere((e) => e['location'] == (location ?? widget.location));
    if (index < 0) {
      index = 0;
    }

    _tabController.animateTo(index);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _tabController = TabController(length: menu.length, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        currentPageIndex = _tabController.index;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(MainPage oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    changePage(location: widget.location);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: List.generate(menu.length, (index) => 
          KeepAliveClient(
            child: menu[index]['page'] as Widget
          )
        )
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        destinations: [...]
        selectedIndex: currentPageIndex,
        onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
          context.go(menu[index]['path']);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Even though it worked, I still felt like something was wrong. It would be great if someone could show me some more professional way

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with the StatefulShellRoute. It is a little more complicated to setup but it is worth it and you can even scale it up to a responsive design afterward. I recently wrote an article on this that will also explain how to unit test it. You can find the article [here](https://medium.com/@gbaccetta/a-complete-guide-to-a-scalable-app-in-flutter-part-4-complex-navigation-and-responsive-layout-73c96b6d8f12).

A more simplified version than what I wrote in my article would look like this ( I use a StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack that simplify things a little bit and will make each branch correspond to an index starting at 0 and corresponding to each tab in order)

```
class AppRouter {
  static final GoRouter simpleRouter = GoRouter(
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
        name: RoutesNames.home,
        path: '/',
        redirect: (_, __) => Routes.articles(),
      ),
      StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
        pageBuilder: (context, state, navigationShell) => FadeTransitionPage(
          key: state.pageKey,
          child: HomeView(nestedNavigator: NestedNavigator(navigationShell)),
        ),
        branches: <StatefulShellBranch>[
          StatefulShellBranch(
            routes: <GoRoute>[
              GoRoute(
                name: RoutesNames.articles,
                path: '/${PathSegments.articles}',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const ArticleListView(),
                routes: <GoRoute>[
                  GoRoute(
                    name: RoutesNames.articleDetails,
                    path: ':${PathParams.articleId}',
                    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                        ArticleDetailsView(articleId: articleId),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            routes: <GoRoute>[
              GoRoute(
                name: RoutesNames.user,
                path: '/${PathSegments.user}',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const Center(child: Text('User page')),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  );
```

}

The NestedNavigator I use is just a wrapper:

```
class NestedNavigator {
  final StatefulNavigationShell statefulNavigationShell;
  NestedNavigator(this.statefulNavigationShell);

  Widget get navigatorContainer => statefulNavigationShell;
  int get currentIndex => statefulNavigationShell.currentIndex;
  void goBranch(int index) => statefulNavigationShell.goBranch(index);
}
```

And the HomeView will use statefulNavigationShell as state management for the current tab and the navigation trough the `goBranch` method. goBranch is what allows to keep navigation state between tabs.

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  final NestedNavigator nestedNavigator;
  const HomeView({super.key, required this.nestedNavigator});
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  /// this is the list of our tabs
  final _destinations = const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.article_outlined),
      activeIcon: Icon(Icons.article),
      label: 'Articles',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.person_2_outlined),
      activeIcon: Icon(Icons.person_2),
      label: 'User',
    ),
  ];

  /// This is a simple helper method to convert NavBar items to NavRail items
  NavigationRailDestination _toRailDestination(BottomNavigationBarItem item) =>
      NavigationRailDestination(
        label: Text(item.label!),
        icon: item.icon,
        selectedIcon: item.activeIcon,
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AdaptiveLayout(
        internalAnimations: false,
        primaryNavigation: SlotLayout(
          config: <Breakpoint, SlotLayoutConfig>{
            // On medium screen we will use a navigation rail
            Breakpoints.medium: SlotLayout.from(
              key: const Key('Primary Navigation Medium'),
              builder: (_) => AdaptiveScaffold.standardNavigationRail(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                selectedIndex: widget.nestedNavigator.currentIndex,
                onDestinationSelected: goToTab,
                destinations: _destinations
                    .map((item) => _toRailDestination(item))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
            // On large screens we will use a drawer (extended version of the rail)
            Breakpoints.large: SlotLayout.from(
              key: const Key('Primary Navigation Large'),
              builder: (_) => AdaptiveScaffold.standardNavigationRail(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                selectedIndex: widget.nestedNavigator.currentIndex,
                onDestinationSelected: goToTab,
                extended: true,
                destinations: _destinations
                    .map((item) => _toRailDestination(item))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
          },
        ),
        // BottomNavigation is only active in small views defined as under 600 dp
        bottomNavigation: SlotLayout(
          config: <Breakpoint, SlotLayoutConfig>{
            Breakpoints.small: SlotLayout.from(
              key: const Key('Bottom Navigation Small'),
              builder: (_) => BottomNavigationBar(
                items: _destinations,
                currentIndex: widget.nestedNavigator.currentIndex,
                onTap: goToTab,
              ),
            )
          },
        ),
        // Body will just contain the nested navigator for all screen sizes.
        // Each nested view could eventually use adaptiveLayout again if needed
        // Hence we won't use a secondary body in our home_view
        body: SlotLayout(
          config: <Breakpoint, SlotLayoutConfig>{
            Breakpoints.smallAndUp: SlotLayout.from(
              key: const Key('Nested navigator'),
              builder: (_) => widget.nestedNavigator.navigatorContainer,
            ),
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void goToTab(int index) {
    widget.nestedNavigator.goBranch(index);
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer how to use it with TabBarView, the difference with `BottomNavigationBar` is that there is no animation or swiping between pages

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
 StatefulShellRoute(
   builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell) {
     return navigationShell;
   },
   navigatorContainerBuilder: (BuildContext context, StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell, List<Widget> children) {
     return TabbedRootScreen(navigationShell: navigationShell, children: children);
   },
   branches: [...]
)
```

and then on TabbedRootScreen use these children in TabBarView